# Show progress bar with percentage while downloading file using Volley in android

Tags: android, download, android-volley

I am using volley to download file using an asynchronous task.I want to show the progress with percentage while the file is being downloaded. But the problem is that the async task is started when the response has come. I can't find any way to track the progress before final response has completely come. 
I didn't find any method in JsonRequest that can be used for this.

Below is the onResponse method of request class that extends JsonRequest  that i am using.

```
 protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
                // If the status is correct, we return a success but with a null object, because the server didn't return anything
                return Response.success(null, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
         else {
            try {
                if (downloadFlag) {
                    DownloadFileAsyncTask downloadFileAsyncTask = new DownloadFileAsyncTask(mContext, fileNameAndExtn,mNotifyManager,mBuilder,mDownloadNotificationUniqueId);
                    downloadFileAsyncTask.execute(response.data);
                } else if (isResponseByteArr) {
                    return (Response<T>) Response.success(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                } else {
                  String json = null;
                    if (isGzipped(response)) {
                        json = gzipDecompress(response.data);
                    } else {
                        json = new String(response.data,HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    }

                    T parsedObject = gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
                    return Response.success(parsedObject, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

DownFileAsyncTask is as follows:
    package com.android.webframework.webservice;

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.applogger.AppLogger;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DownloadFileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Integer, String> {
    private String fileNameAndExtn;
    private Context mContext;
    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    private int mUniqueId;

    public DownloadFileAsyncTask(Context context, String fileNameAndExtn, NotificationManager notifyManager, NotificationCompat.Builder builder, int uniqueId) {
        this.fileNameAndExtn = fileNameAndExtn;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mNotifyManager = notifyManager;
        this.mBuilder = builder;
        this.mUniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    String MEDIA_MOUNTED = "mounted";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... bytes) {
        File file = null;
        int copyCount = 0;
        String filePath = "";
        String diskState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (diskState.equalsIgnoreCase(MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            file = new File(sd, fileNameAndExtn);

            String fileName = "";
            String fileExtn;

            String fileNameToSave = fileNameAndExtn;

            while (file.exists()) {

                copyCount++;

                String[] parts = fileNameAndExtn.split("[.]");

                if (parts[0] != null)
                    fileName = parts[0];

                fileName += "-" + copyCount;

                fileNameToSave = fileName + "." + parts[1];

                file = new File(sd, fileNameToSave);

            }

            fileNameAndExtn = fileNameToSave;

            /*if (file.exists()) {

                file.delete();
            }*/

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
                fos.write(bytes[0]);
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                AppLogger.e("file", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
            }
            AppLogger.e("file Download completed", "***************");

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
            mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

            filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "The external disk is not mounted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return (filePath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String filePath) {
        super.onPostExecute(filePath);
        if (fileNameAndExtn != null && !fileNameAndExtn.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
//            Toast.makeText(mContext, "File downloaded in Downloads/" + fileNameAndExtn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, fileNameAndExtn + " downloaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, 100, false);
            Intent intent = getPendingIntent(mContext, filePath);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(fileNameAndExtn)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText("Download complete");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
            if (intent != null) {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
            }

            if (pendingIntent != null) {
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setProgress(0, 0, false);
            }

            mNotifyManager.notify(mUniqueId, mBuilder.build());

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(mUniqueId, mBuilder.build());
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    public Intent getPendingIntent(Context context, String filePath) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//                File file = new File("YOUR_SONG_URI"); // set your audio path
        File file = new File(filePath);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), getMimeType(filePath));

        if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(context.getApplicationContext().
                getPackageManager(), 0) != null) {
//            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            return intent;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "File not present or Explorer app not present.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
            // if you reach this place, it means there is no any file
            // explorer app installed on your device
        }
    }

    public static String getMimeType(String url) {
        String filePathWithoutWhiteSpace = url.replaceAll("\\s", "%20");
        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(filePathWithoutWhiteSpace);
        if (extension != null) {
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.toLowerCase());
        }
        return type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating the notification as soon as the user clicks on download and then the async task notifies after the download is completed but i was not able to show the exact progress while downloading.

Answer (score 0):

not sure you can do this with volley but easy solution for you as you are already using AsyncTask. Here is a link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/ he did the same thing which you are looking.